# Variable's value is being constantly updated by a function. How to use this variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable `distance` whose value is being constantly updated by a function `a`.

Inside the function, there is an infinite loop which keeps on changing the value of `distance`.

I want to work with this variable and be able to write statements like 
`if distance ==0:`.

I feel this won't be possible as we want to execute two tasks simultaneously, one which is updating the value of `distance` and the other one being the conditional statement. The code would never reach the conditional statement since it will remain inside the infinite loop forever.

How do I do this?

Added some code for reference:

```
def a():
    global distance
    while True:
       distance+=1

def b():
    #want to call a so that distance keeps on getting updated
    if distance < 100: 
       print ("I am the best")
```

Comment: Why can you *not* write `if distance == 0` *even if* it's constantly being updated…? This question needs more context.

Comment: How are they able to execute simultaneously?

Comment: @leewz That is what I am asking. Is there a way that I am able to execute both the operations simultaneously .i.e the value of distance keeps on changing and whenever distance =0 , I do some other task

Comment: For this you need either asynchronous execution or at least two threads. If you just have a simple `for` loop which constantly changes the value, then no other code can run at the same time, so the problem of accessing it is moot.

Comment: @deceze Did not understand anything that you just said

Comment: Ditto. Then you better add some example code to your question to create some common ground.

Comment: added some code as an example

Comment: Yeah, since you have an infinite loop there, nothing else is ever going to happen outside that loop. Your code will never exit `while True` and hence will never call `b()`. Again, you need to look into *multi-threaded execution*, *asynchronous execution*, or change your approach for whatever you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: Will multithreaded execution  work with infinite loop?

Comment: Generally speaking yes. The details may be more hairy. This is not a topic to discuss in comments. Read something about the basics and ask a new question if you need details.

Comment: can you please remove on hold tag on this question

Comment: An alternative to multithreading is rewriting the infinite loop ass a finite state machines. The main program is an infinite loop, which calls each of the machines, which update their state then return, one call = one iteration.